# NSDictionary return value with Parentheses

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, nsdictionary

I assign JSON values to NSDictionary and try to retrive Key's from the dictionary. It returns the value with the parentheses!

**This is the value it returns**
(
    873
) , (
    "HST 299"
)

**Here is the JSON**

```
[{"_id":873,"_code":"HST 299"}]
```

**Here is my code:**

```
NSDictionary *courseDetail = [responseString JSONValue];
NSLog(@"%@ , %@", [courseDetail valueForKey:@"_id"], [courseDetail valueForKey:@"_code"]);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because your JSON is an array (`[]` means array).
And there is ONE dictionary with TWO key-values in the array.

So, if you change your code into

```
NSDictionary *courseDetail = [[responseString JSONValue] objectAtIndex:0];
```

it will gives you the correct result.

Comment: Thank you it worked! One more issue: application crash when I assign to the label. For example courseId.text = [courseDetail valueForKey:@"_id"]; Do I need to convert the integer?

Comment: It looks like the _id is a NSNumber but not a NSString. So you have to convert it into a NSString. :)

Comment: In addition, you can always check what kind of Class is your object by using code like this: `if ([[dict objectForKey:@"key"] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])`. If it's a NSString, you can set it to label.text directly, otherwise you have to convert it into a NSString by yourself.

Answer (score 7):

Parentheses are how NSArrays describe themselves. Your values are apparently arrays that each contain a single string, not bare strings.

Comment: So, you mean I should use NSArray instead of NSDictionary?

Comment: @Mr. D: you can do `[courseDetail valueForKey:@"_id"] objectAtIndex:0]` and it will work.

Comment: @xuzhe: Nope, I'm right. `valueForKey:` on an array returns an array of the objects' responses to `valueForKey:`, so his values are indeed arrays containing single objects. He had not posted his JSON at the time, so I didn't know this was because he had an array to begin with, but my answer is still correct as far as it goes.